# Windows Explorer view doesn't work after upgrade from 2007 to 2010

Tags: 2010, upgrade, explorer-view, open-with-explorer

We have upgraded a MOSS 2007 publishing site to SharePoint 2010 Enterprise. Having done this we have found problems with opening Document Libraries in Explorer View.

Most users access the site via http and view published pages only. Content Editors use a secondary URL via https.

Explorer View worked fine on the 2007 site and we have mirrored the set up from the old site, but it returns the error message "your client does not support opening this list in Windows Explorer".

Comment: Are you using a win 2008 server to browse the site? Which browser you're using?

Comment: The servers running SharePoint 2010 are Win 2008 R2. The clients are Win 7 and we've tried both IE8 and 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same issue as you with migrated content from 2007 to 2010. After your usual checks (i.e. traffic is over port 80/443 & you have a user profile service application associated to the web application), try creating a new document library in the affected site collection, and then attempt to open via explorer view. If this works for you, next try to open the affected form libraries using the Explorer View button on the ribbon. Hey presto, it might just come to life!

Thanks,
Andy